# Where to place JS link in DispForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, dispform

Whenever I place my js link:

```
<script src="/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/js/xxx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Under

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server">
```

It does not work but it works if I place the entire js such as (rather than a link to the js file containing the  same code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myPrintBtn() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

I need to add a custom print header and footer and rather than adding the script on each list's DispForm.asxp, I was hoping I could just reference the js file.

Answer (score 0):

For classic view, you could inject custom JS by `[Add-PnPJavaScriptLink][1]`, demo:

```
Connect-PNPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev
Add-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name "hideOptionsForRequestAccess" -Url /sites/dev/SiteAssets/hideOptionsForRequestAccess.js -Sequence 9999 -Scope Site
```

In JS logic, you could add custom logic(check whether url is display form).

Below function is used for different scenario, just for your reference.

```
(function() {
    // Load the script
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onload = function() {
        var $ = window.jQuery;          
        var style = $('<style>.ms-accRqCllOt-PrmCmbBx option[value="SharePoint Group#7"]{ display: none; }.ms-accRqCllOt-PrmCmbBx option[value="SharePoint Group#8"]{ display: none; }</style>');
        $('html > head').append(style);     
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
})();
```